# LinearLayout with layout_weights with childs with different heights

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My image button is 40px in height, but my gallery is a lot bigger in height.  Right now, my imagebuttons take up the entire space they are given, and is the same height as my gallery.  Is there anway to keep the buttons their original size while keeping this horizontal layout?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left_arrow"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shared_arrow_left_button_selector"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spacing="15dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shared_arrow_right_button_selector"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add your starting tag of LinearLayout, so that I can understand it better?

Comment: update also with the screen shot you are getting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to both the ImageButtons so they are filling the height, if you just want ImageButtons to wrap their original size just change them to `wrap_content` and remove the `layout_weight` property. Also when you are applying `layout_weight="1"` to gallery just change `android:layout_width="0dp"` as the width will be managed by the `layout_weight` property itself. Your final layout should be like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:spacing="15dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the layout weight = 3 in ImageButtons, it is the cause to show image button bigger than Gallery.

I think you don't know how to use layout_weight property, so that you don't know how to solve this problem. First know about layout_weight.

If you have any doubt feel free to ask me.

Use below lines in both image buttons and gallery, it will be nice.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: I thought weights were used to dynamically size the widths of views

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/left_arrow"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shared_arrow_left_button_selector"
        android:scaleType="centerinside" />
Remove Weight attribute, and set width and height of buttons to wrap_content
    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spacing="15dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shared_arrow_right_button_selector"
        android:scaleType="centerinside" />
</LinearLayout>
```